# Handle http 5xx responses in spring WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-webflux

I have a Spring Boot 3 application (using reactive stack). I want to add specific body to all responses that would return HTTP 5xx. How would I go about implementing such a functionality. I tried using `@RestControllerAdvice` that listens to `Exception.class` but this does not work because it could also change HTTP 4xx responses and also I could have exceptions that I want to handle differently.

For example, if NullPointerException happens in application then my rest service would return HTTP 500, but I want to add some helpful information to the body of the response so that frontend can display it to the end user.